# Wordpress widget unique selector in admin panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, dom

The admin section for a widget renders (server-side) once, after that WordPress duplicates that piece of HTML to for example the footer section.

Probably by doing something like this:

```js
document.getElementById('widget-selector').innerHTML = '<div>My admin HTML</div>';
```

Unique ID attributes generated server side are now duplicated and my frontend is heavily relying on JavaScript (jQuery), setting for example click handlers for specific elements within my admin section are messing up.

I could use: `$('selector').last();` but I'm not sure if that is a reliable method since it isn't always the last element with that selector.

Any idea's or suggestions on how to get the correct selectors?

I hope I elaborated enough, let me know if I'm missing something and I will edit my question.

**EDIT**

After looking some more on StackOverflow and the WordPress documentation, WordPress emits the following event: `widget-added` whenever a widget is dropped on one of the widget sections, here is some example code.

> ```
> $(document).on('widget-added', function(event, widget){
>     const widgetId = $(widget).attr('id');
>     /**
>      * widgetId is something like widget-8_my-plugin-name-widget-7, 
>      * inside that element is your widgets HTML, so check if this is your plugin
>      */
>     if (widgetId.match(/my-plugin-name/)) {
>         /** 
>         * i have a button with class .my-button somewhere in the widget
>         * so make the following selector: #widget-8_my-plugin-name-widget-7 .my-button
>         */ 
>         $('#' + widgetId + ' .my-button').on('click', function() {
>             console.log('test');
>         });
>     }
> });
> ```

This solves the issue when new widgets are drag & dropped to one of the widget area's, I'm still looking for a reliable way to get the selector when they are first rendered (server-side).